# DOMDocument error when loading image

Tags: php, domdocument

I have an error like this :

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied

the element sent is like this with `$image` :

```
`<img alt="" src="/boutique/sources/images/attributes_options/carre_rouge.jpg" style="width: 320px; height: 320px;" /`>
```

Same is the element is saved correctly inside the db, This error appear.
Any idea to solve ?

Thank you.
My function

```
public static function getCkeditorImageAlone($image) {
  $OSCOM_Template = Registry::get('TemplateAdmin');

  var_dump($image);

  $doc = new \DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($image);
  $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
  $image = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");

  $image = OSCOM::getConfig('http_server', 'Shop') . $image;

  $image = htmlspecialchars($image);
  $image = strstr($image, $OSCOM_Template->getDirectoryShopTemplateImages());
  $image = str_replace($OSCOM_Template->getDirectoryShopTemplateImages(), '', $image);
  $image_end = strstr($image, '&quot;');
  $image = str_replace($image_end, '', $image);
  $image = str_replace($OSCOM_Template->getDirectoryShopSources(), '', $image);

  return $image;
}
```

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($image);`?

Comment: find the solution : I make this :            `if (isset($value['image']) && !is_null($value['image']) && !empty($value['image'])) {
              $option_image = $this->getCkeditorImageAlone($value['image']);
            } else {
              $option_image = $value['info_image'];
            }`

Comment: Its generally not a good idea to overwrite a variable with a completely different kind of variable in so many ways. You run the risk that some of those returns are references or objects.

Comment: @IncredibleHat. How do you make this ? I mut have just this element to write in bd : attributes_options/carre_rouge.jpg